# communicate between today widget and application

Tags: ios, macos, today-extension

I have a today widget and an application. The need is to communicate between them so that information can be passed any any point of time when both are running.

I can achieve communicating tow application on Mac application using NSProxy, setting one process as server.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communication between `Host App` and `Today Extension`:

1. To share data: use `AppGroups`
2. To share code: use `Frameworks`

Refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

For more on how to implement `Today Extension`: https://github.com/pgpt10/Today-Widget

Comment: Thanks for replying. Like music application i can play pause next action when the host application is running. Cannot i have the similar functionality, where a button action will make host app to undergo an operation and notify the widget for completion.

Comment: Do you want to open the host app on button click?

Comment: I do not want to open the app. Consider app is running in background or foreground, i want some operation to be carried out in host app which is initiated from widget and inform the status for the same. after which i will get the data from userdefaults. Music application widget do not need to open the host app, if it already running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate between today extension and your app. you can use nsuserdefaults.

There is good tutorial for this. [app-extension-programming-today](http://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/)